# How to make a higher div inside a div

Tags: html, css

i have two divs , one is higher than other , what i want is to put the first one that's higher inside the other .

```
#bottom {
    overflow-x:scroll ;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    position:fixed;
    height:45px;
    width:864px;
    background-color:yellow;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-left:144px;
}
.box {
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer ;
vertical-align: middle;
width:200px; height:525px; 
background:blue;
left:144px; 
margin-right: 16px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to put one div inside another? You do that in your markup, not the css.

Can you please post your HTML as well, and your question might be a bit clearer.

Edit: http://jsfiddle.net/gF8ch/1/ Jsfiddle with `div inside div.`

Comment: '<div id="bottom"><div class="box"  ></div></div>' this is the html ,

Comment: Just switch them around then if you want bottom inside box?

<div class="box">
    <div id="bottom"></div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it only with `CSS` and `HTML`
You can use jQuery:

```
$('#whereToPut').appendTo('#whatToPut');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...You want to set the position of the divs..

```
.box {
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer ;
vertical-align: middle;
width:200px; height:525px; 
background:blue;
left:144px; 
margin-right: 16px
}

#bottom {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x:scroll ;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;    
    position:fixed;
    height:45px;
    width:864px;
    background-color:yellow;
    bottom:0px;
    margin-left:144px;
}
```

You want to make the higher `Position:absolute` and the second div `Position:relative` and after that you can place the second div inside the higher div..

You can refer the following links for clarifications..

[Positioning two divs..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12992196/positioning-a-div-inside-another-div)

[Positioning html controls..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068624/how-to-place-div-inside-another-div-to-absolute-position)

Comment: Please feel free to ask for clarifications and mark as answer if it satisfies,Regards...

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
(My Understanding is that you want change the child to parent and parent to child)

```
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
var box = document.getElementById("box");

bottom.parentNode.appendChild(box); // appending box to the bottom's parent
bottom.innerHTML = "";              // clearing bottom's children
box.appendChild(bottom);            // appending bottom to box
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in the `div`'s `style` that you want to be the top :

```
z-index:10000;
```

If not enough change 10000 to something you want.